# objective-C: string with variable

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective-C and I need help adding a variable to a string. in java, to add a variable to a string you have to do something like this:

```
 output = "Area: " + area + '\n' +"Circumference: " + circumference;
```

I can't figure out how to put that together to one string.

i have tried:

```
NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area : %.03f", area , "Circumference: %.03f", circumference];
```

and a couple other ways but it seems to not work.

Comment: What's type of area?

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C requires you to define the format first and then pass the parameters.

Use this instead:

```
NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area : %.03f Circumference: %.03f", area, circumference];
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would say you need to learn more and see books and other references [like](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

here is how you will do in objective c

```
 NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area : %.03f Circumference: %.03f", area , circumference];
```